Add functions to context when using python eval
I'd like to define some contextual functions that can then be used later, as per the example below.
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def g(x):
    u = my_func(x, 4 ** x)
    return my_func(u, u // 2)

eval('g(1)', globals() | {'my_func': add})

This code throws NameError: name 'my_func' is not defined. Is there any way to achieve this (ideally without changing the functions add and g)?

the problem here is that the function g refers to the globals() where it is defined, not in the context of eval (IOW, lexical scope)

almost certainly, though, eval is the wrong approach. what is your use case exactly?

When a function executes it looks up a name in the global namespace referenced by the function's __globals__ attribute, rather than the global namespace in which the call is made, so you would have to inject my_func into the function's __globals__ dict instead:
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def g(x):
    u = my_func(x, 4 ** x)
    return my_func(u, u // 2)

g.__globals__['my_func'] = add
eval('g(1)')

Demo: https://ideone.com/JVFRYE

A way to do this is to pass the function as an argument. However, you have to slightly edit your g() function for that:
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def g(my_func, x):
    u = my_func(x, 4 ** x)
    return my_func(u, u // 2)

functs = {'my_func': add}
eval(f'g({functs["my_func"].__name__}, 1)', globals())

Here, I pass the callable add as an argument. Due to the eval, I have to convert it as a string so it takes the __name__ field.
